# Duplicate text using Blaze without using helper

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

In a Meteor template with Blaze I want to simply duplicate a piece of text entered by the user onto another part of the screen. Is there a way to do this without writing helper JS code? Something like:

```
<input value="{{theValue}}" type="text">
<p>{{theValue}}</p>
```

I don't want to store the data in a collection, just duplicate it. Seems like this can't be done without writing a JS helper.

Comment: Did u check this one https://viewmodel.meteor.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help. I've switched to angular-meteor

Comment: I'm curious, what do you mean "it doesn't help"? (since you can do exactly that with ViewModel)

Comment: @Manuel You're right, it does help. I decided to go with Angular because there is a larger community of developers.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said,i am unaware of any method too without writing a helper for this,
if you are taking the user's input and then you want to display it elsewhere,it would be best to store the input in a Session or reactive variable and then later display it with a helper

in the input event

```
Session.set("inputValue",the-user's value);
```

and return a helper wherever you want to display it

```
 'userValue' : function(){
return Session.get("inputValue");
```

anyway i would update the answer if i find something that can be done without using a helper

Comment: How to solve error?Exception in thread "Rules agent factory thread for com.blazesoft.server.local.NdLocalServiceAgentDispenser@21408926" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fico/decmethod/dag/DAG
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fico/decmethod/dag/DAG